# SQL Multiple Joins multiple where

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables is question. categories, vocabulary & tex. I am trying to figure out how to have multiple joins in my query, i thought you can just add as many joins as you wanted, as long as you reference them properly.

So, the following two work perfectly on there own:

1.

```
SELECT 
categories.ID AS ID,
categories.ParentID AS ID,
vocabulary.value AS Name
FROM categories
INNER JOIN vocabulary
ON categories.sid=vocabulary.sid
WHERE vocabulary.langid=1
```

2.

```
SELECT 
categories.ID AS ID,
categories.ParentID AS ID,
tex.value AS Description
FROM categories
INNER JOIN tex
ON categories.tid=tex.tid
WHERE tex.langid=1
```

However, if i try to combine them as follows, it does not work.

```
categories.ID AS ID,
categories.ParentID AS ID,
vocabulary.value AS Name
tex.value AS Description
FROM categories
INNER JOIN tex
ON categories.tid=tex.tid
WHERE tex.langid=1

INNER JOIN vocabulary
ON categories.sid=vocabulary.sid
WHERE vocabulary.langid=1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
John

Comment: `INNER JOIN WHAT_TABLE_DO_YOU_WANT_TO_JOIN` ? (probably `tex` )

Comment: "Does not work" could mean many things. You got an error? The results are not what you expect?  Solutions are different for each.

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL`, when you have columns with the same name, one of them will only be shown. You need to identify them uniquely by supplying `ALIAS`. And you can either put the condition on the `ON` clause or `WHERE` clause which could yield the same result since it uses `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT  categories.ID AS CategoryID,
        categories.ParentID AS CategoryParentID,
        vocabulary.value AS Name
        tex.value AS Description
FROM    categories
        INNER JOIN tex
            ON categories.tid = tex.tid
        INNER JOIN vocabulary
            ON categories.sid = vocabulary.sid
WHERE   vocabulary.langid = 1 AND 
        tex.langid = 1
```

Comment: @wildplasser yep, copy-paste.

Comment: @491243 so is the only error that i should have had both where statements at the bottom? Thanks for your help.

Comment: it should only have one `WHERE` clause.

Comment: and i spotted in my question that i forgot to add join the tables i want to join. oopps,

Comment: @user2231688 yep, i know it was a typo since you already mentioned that the first two queries above are working.